# Python Error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xde in position 1187: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("online_retail.csv")
```

Here I am able to read and create the dataframe as df and 'Quantity' is a column in dataframe(df)

```
df[df['Quantity'] > 500]
```

I am facing below error while running this line of code:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xde in position 1187: invalid continuation byte

I have tried multiple time googling for this error this but didn't get the solution, Please suggest to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open your CSV document with notes for instance and check your 1187 character. It might be a character not in the utf-8 dictionnary or a "\X" with X a character, leading a utf-8 reader to think that it is a command. Share us the document for more details

Comment: Below is the data for lineno: 1187

Comment: 536529,22164,HOLDER,6,01-12-2010 13.20,2.95,14237.0,United Kingdom

Comment: here the issue is with the comprasion and mathematical operator like >,* .
Below code also giving same error
df['InvoiceAmount'] = df['Quantity'] * df['UnitPrice']
df['VAT'] = df['InvoiceAmount'] * 0.08